# Excel - Row-wise calculation without helpers

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

Recently I answered a question about how to retrieve the `MEDIAN()` of each `MEDIAN()` in a 2-column matrix **without helpers**, e.g:

[image]

The row-wise calculation without helpers wasn't too hard because the median with only two values is always the average. Therefor a simple formula was all it took:

```
=MEDIAN((A1:A3+B1:B3)/2)
```

But for curiosity sakes however, wat if I would have at least a 3-column matrix?

[image]

The median will actually need to be calculated. Here the medians are `{8,2,2}`.

I can't seem to find a way to to get a row-wise calculation for 3+columns. In this case it's about `MEDIAN()` but I can imagine there could be other functionalities. Since this could be simplified data I don't want to resort to something like `=MEDIAN(MEDIAN(A1:C1),MEDIAN(.....`.

I tried to fiddle around with `OFFSET()`, though not a fan of volatile functions I was hoping it would either work directly with an array, or would be triggered correctly through using `MEDIAN(LET(X,SEQUENCE(ROWS(A1:A3)),MEDIAN(OFFSET(A1:C1,X-1,0))))`. I then moved on to combinations of either `MMULT()` or `LARGE()`, however none of my attempt were succesfull.

**Question**

So the question ultimately is; how do we return the result (array) of an row-wise calculation without helpers. And if not possible, that's also a perfectly fine answer so I can rest my head =)

Comment: The problem is that Median accepts arrays as input, so the first Median, even if you were to get the offset correct would capture all the array and find the median of that and pass only one number to the outer median.

Comment: SUM, AVERAGE, MIN, MAX do the same thing.

Comment: @ScottCraner, exactly my problem. Though `SUM()` and `AVERAGE()` we can deal with through `MMULT()`, I was hoping there is a more generalized way of doing a per-row calculation. A "no that's not possibble" is perfectly acceptable too.

Comment: Which means I do not think it possible.  With the others we can use the *IFS() formulas and OFFSET to do what you want, but there is no MEDIANIFS()

Comment: @ScottCraner, maybe a recursive `LAMBDA()` can get us anywhere? However, I do not yet have got that function.

Comment: maybe try offset in a LARGE that returns the middle number then take the median of that?

Comment: I have tried for the past 90 minutes, I do not think it possible.

Comment: @ScottCraner, if also you have given up I'll also throw in the towel. That is atleast untill `LAMBDA()` comes around. Who know.... it may still be possible =)

Comment: You could use LET in this fashion: `=LET(x,MEDIAN(A1:C1),y,MEDIAN(A2:C2),z,MEDIAN(A3:C3),MEDIAN(x,y,z))` But that is not very scalable, and my reading on Lamda is that it would need to be used in a similar fashion.  But we will see.

Comment: @ScottCraner.....my head hurts but.....I think I cracked it =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***New Answer***

With the new [`BYROW()`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/byrow-function-2e04c677-78c8-4e6b-8c10-a4602f2602bb) function one could use:

```
=MEDIAN(BYROW(A1:C3,LAMBDA(a,MEDIAN(a))))
```

The nested `LAMBDA()` in the 2nd parameter makes it a piece o' cake to loop all rows in a dynamic array (not a range per se).

---

***Previous Answer** (Pre-BYROW())*

So. After a long thought, as far as my understanding goes this is not possible through current formulae. However, currently in BETA, Excel365 will feature the new `LAMBDA()` function which makes it possible to create your own function without VBA and even recursively call itself. It isn't the prettiest of solutions but I thought I would share what I did here:

[image]

Formula in `E3`:

```
=MED(A1:C3,"",ROWS(A1:A3))
```

Where `MED()` is our own `LAMBDA()` function created at the "name manager" menu. It reads:

```
 =LAMBDA(rng,txt,rws,IF(rws=0,MEDIAN(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&txt&"</s></t>","//s")),MED(rng,TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",,txt,MEDIAN(INDEX(rng,rws;0))),rws-1)))
```

As can be seen there are 4 main parameters of which 3 variables:

- `rng` - The range to be examined.
- `txt` - A reserved variable to be used in `FILTERXML()`.
- `rws` - A counter.

The 4th parameter is a nested `IF()` which if the counter is as 0 will return the median of all medians. This is done through `FILTERXML()` which I will not get into detail right now.

If the counter is not yet at 0 it will recursively call the `LAMBDA()` function untill it is, and what it does is using the same three parameters but we can alter them right there and then. Therefor we leave `rng` intact, we concatenate the `MEDIAN()` of the row (current counter) through `TEXTJOIN()` to create a valid xml construct. And last but not least we need to lower the counter.

It's a struggle, but with `LAMBDA()` it will now be possible to do a rowwise calculation.

Note, if you are interested in the `FILTERXML()` construct, you might like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61837696/9758194) post where I now also included a `LAMBDA()` version of a `SPLIT()` function.

Comment: I do not have lambda yet.  but fascinating that you can do recursive.  That is awesome.  I will need to play with it when I finally get it.

Comment: @ScottCraner. Have a look at your account, I didn't have it untill today but then I realised I wasn't an insider yet. It's a simple button with a switch to say you want the BETA environment. It opens many opportunities. I dived right in to create a recursive substitution of characters instead of nested `SUBSTITUTES()`. Very fun!

Comment: I was not on beta chanel.

Comment: There you go. Time to switch the channel and get an update =) @ScottCraner